# try/except/finally in Coroutine

Tags: python, coroutine, finally

```
class DemoException(Exception):   
    """An exception type for the demonstration."""

def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    while True:
        try:
            x = yield
        except DemoException:  # <1>
            print('*** DemoException handled. Continuing...')
        else:  # <2>
            print('-> coroutine received: {!r}'.format(x))
        finally:
            print('-> 1111111111coroutine ending')
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
exc_coro = demo_exc_handling()
next(exc_coro)
exc_coro.send(11)
```

I get the following output:

```
-> coroutine started
-> coroutine received: 11
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
```

I want to know why the finally statement executes twice?
I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints twice because the finally clause executes even if the main program ends.

The coroutine is yielding the second time when the main program ends

Let's yield the iteration number and add a couple of printouts to see it

```
class DemoException(Exception):   
    """An exception type for the demonstration."""
    pass

def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    i = 1
    while True:
        try:
            print(f"iteration {i}")
            x = yield i
        except DemoException:  # <1>
            print('*** DemoException handled. Continuing...')
        else:  # <2>
            print('-> coroutine received: {!r}'.format(x))
        finally:
            print('-> 1111111111coroutine ending')
        i += 1
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exc_coro = demo_exc_handling()
    print("initialised")
    y = next(exc_coro)
    print(f"got {y}")
    exc_coro.send(11)
```

produces

```
initialised
-> coroutine started
iteration 1
got 1
-> coroutine received: 11
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
iteration 2
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. After reading your answer, could I understand it like this:  when main program ends, the coroutin will terminate either. because the coroutin suspends in a yield where is in try-except-finally block, it will execute finally clause then terminate.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with coroutines or exceptions. Just a generator will reproduce fine:

```
def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    while True:
        try:
            x = yield
        finally:
            print('-> 1111111111coroutine ending')
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exc_coro = demo_exc_handling()
    next(exc_coro)
    next(exc_coro)
```

Here is the output:

```
-> coroutine started
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
```

What you probably meant to do was have the while loop INSIDE the try-finally:

```
def demo_exc_handling():
    print('-> coroutine started')
    try:
        while True:
            x = yield
    finally:
        print('-> 1111111111coroutine ending')
    raise RuntimeError('This line should never run.')
```

which instead outputs

```
-> coroutine started
-> 1111111111coroutine ending
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes it does. The author switched the order of two loops. It executes twice because the loops are not in the order the author thinks they are. A "finally" clause always executes when completing the "try", which happens twice.

Comment: "A "finally" clause always executes when completing the "try" " helps me. thank you.